# Managing arguments from a path with Python

Tags: python, string, powershell, path

I'm having problems working with a path I'm retreiving from a PowerShell script in my python Script.

Just to give context, this is how I'm retrieving the information I need in PowerShell:

```
$dataKey = 'cmd /K "ipy.exe C:\MiCarpetaPython\CompilerTool.py %1"'

New-Item -Path $commandKey -Force
Set-ItemProperty -Path $commandKey -Name '(default)' -Value $dataKey
```

For those of you reading that doesn't understand what %1 does, it gives you the path of the file you execute your shortcut with, so in my case, I'm getting:

C:\Users\223122412\Documents\FIFA\1_RVS.zip
(I believe this part is correct and the most efficient way to retrieve what I need)

But this is the important part, the part I'm having trouble with:
(my python code)

```
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: python CompilerTool.py <ZipFileName> <DirectoryOfZip>")
    sys.exit(1)
C:\Users\223122412\Documents\F10X

source_zip_file = sys.argv[1]
folder_name = os.path.basename(source_zip_file)
directory_of_zip = os.path.dirname(source_zip_file)
```

As I already explained in the Powershell part, with %1 I'm getting the complete path of my file, but the way that I'm intended to use it is:

```
#"C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\ipy.exe" CompilerTool.py 1_RVS.ZIP C:\Users\223122412\Documents\FIFA
```

The structure should be: "path to iron python" "python script" "zip name with the extension" "folder that the zip is located"

So the question is how do I convert this:

```
C:\Users\223122412\Documents\FIFA\1_RVS.zip
```

into:

```
1_RVS.zip C:\Users\223122412\Documents\FIFA
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the full file path into separate command-line arguments, you can modify your PowerShell script to split the path and pass these as individual arguments to your Python script. Following is the updated PowerShell script:

```
$fullPath = "C:\Users\223122412\Documents\FIFA\1_RVS.zip"
$fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($fullPath)
$directoryPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($fullPath)

$dataKey = 'cmd /K "ipy.exe C:\MiCarpetaPython\CompilerTool.py ' + $fileName + ' ' + $directoryPath + '"'

New-Item -Path $commandKey -Force
Set-ItemProperty -Path $commandKey -Name '(default)' -Value $dataKey
```

The above script will separate the file name and the directory, and pass them as separate arguments to your Python script. Your Python script can then use `sys.argv[1]` to get the filename and `sys.argv[2]` to get the directory path.

Comment: The thing here is that the $fullPath is NOT going to be static, so it will be changing almost every time I run the script

Comment: @JPcoder - You can modify the PowerShell script to accept the path as a parameter. You can then run the PowerShell script and provide the path as an argument.

Comment: What I'm trying to do now is to change the way I'm reading the parameters in python, something like this:


source_zip_file = sys.argv[2]
carpeta, nombre_archivo = os.path.split(source_zip_file)
folder_name = nombre_archivo
directory_of_zip = carpeta

But I don't know if source_zip_file = sys.argv[2] contains the complete path (from the %1)